# Atomikos threads piling up in spring batch application

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, atomikos

Atomikos threads piling up in spring batch application. After a while the application stops working working with an OOM error. With each job triggered in the Spring Batch application number od Atomikos threads are increasing and not getting removed from the thread.

Comment: Which indicates that you are loading everything (the application) each time you need it.

Comment: is there some configuration I can add in the application that I can set to avoid this ? @M.Deinum

Comment: Not loading it each time. This is something you are doing yourself. Probably by having a datasource config in your job configuration instead of reusing an existing one.